# c# and Linq query to object[,]

Tags: c#, excel, linq

I have a list of query results, each containing objects different from the others. I have one type per data set.

```
var myQueryresult = _myContext.TableA
    .Where(a => a.IsToBeProcessed)
    .Select(x => new { ColumnA = x.FieldA, ColumnB =  x.FieldB })
    .ToList();
```

The end goal is to store this data in an Excel sheet using the

```
Range firstCell = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
Range lastCell = sheet.Cells[data.GetLength(0) + 1, data.GetLength(1)];
sheet.Range[firstCell, lastCell].Value2 = myObjectArrayofObjectArrays;
```

I can't seem to find any way to do this but looping on each row of the result.

Comment: You could use a library like EPPlus which can load data from any collection, datatable or datareader directly, eg `var range=sheet.LoadFromCollection(myQueryResult)`. Interop requires installing Excel on the same machine. Libraries like EPPlus don't require anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Excel library's [NamedRange.get_Resize Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.get_resize(v=vs.120).aspx) as well as [NamedRange.set_Value Method (Object, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.set_value.aspx) as follows:

```
Excel.Range testRng = (Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[1, 1];
testRng = testRng.get_Resize(data.GetLength(0), data.GetLength(1));
testRng.set_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, myObjectArrayofObjectArrays);
```

EDIT

I misunderstood the requirements. For your first part it does seem like a loop going through each element is the best method.

Comment: No worries, thanks for taking the time to reply. And yes, that's what I ended doing, good ol' looping.

Answer (score 0):

you can turn your set of data into a datatable via json

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
var table = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(DataTable))
```

and then rely on your engine of choice to output the datatable into excel ready format

Comment: Sorry, I can't upvote you but thanks for taking the time to reply. I ended up looping through my objects to get the job done. Not super efficient but the data volume will never be problematic to this regard.